# Avoid magic string in ASP.NET Core attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-5.0

Consider this example:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("[action]/{id}")
public IActionResult Foo([FromRoute] int id) {
  //etc.
}
```

I can avoid magic strings for areas, controllers, actions by using the special tokens `[controller]`, `[action]`, etc.

This is a simple action with a single `int` argument. Is it also possible somehow to avoid magic string `{id}`?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to write. What would you like to write instead?

Comment: @davidfowl I have no preference other than avoiding magic strings, so off the top of my head, for example, `"[1]"`, or `"[int]"`, or `"[int:1]"`, or `"{...}"`, etc. I was VERY pleased when you guys added the "token" strings (e.g. `"[action]"`), it would be perfect if we could avoid them for arguments as well. There would need to be some compromise, maybe only for single-argument methods.

Comment: @davidfowl Also, by your comment, I assume that the answer to my question is "it cannot be done"?

Comment: It feels like a misunderstanding of something so I'm asking questions to better understand what the problem you're trying to solve is. This is declaring that you want to the routing system to parse this token in the incoming path and call it "id" (if it helps think of it like a regular expression,  even though it isn't one). It's not a magic string in that sense but a way to declare the URL pattern to the routing system.

Comment: @davidfowl Thank you taking the time! I understand your point. My concern is that there will be drift between the string and the argument name, and the route would break, hence I used the term magic string, it was not meant as an offense - I realise you guys try to eliminate magic strings and numbers whenever possible. This situation though seems like another place to reduce the magic. Like I said it would probably only make sense for single-arg actions, but from what I've seen they're the majority. I hope I've explained myself properly.

Comment: I think I finally understand the nuance in your comment. Unless I'm mistaken, what you're saying is there could be all kinds of values in the form/headers/querystring, and so which would you inject into the argument, if it isn't explicitly named? Good point! But if the route is declared as `example.com/[int]` or `example.com/[1]` it would automatically get it from the url (not the form or querystring etc.)

Comment: I wrote a library to avoid magic strings in routes management. It is for javascript, but I'm sure you could write something similar in C#: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@juliushuck/generate-route